# Map enums with mapstruct

Tags: java, enums, mapstruct

I have to make custom mappers on the application I’m working on. Some properties are enum types like this.
I’m trying to figure out how to create a map in this situation.

Here's the property of the entity:

```
@JsonProperty("csp")
private JsonNullable<Csp> csp = JsonNullable.undefined();
```

where `Csp` is an enum

Here's the property of the dto I want to map:

```
private String profession;
```

Here's the map that’s not good:

```
@Mapping(target = "assure", source = "assure", qualifiedByName = "toAssureDto")

@Named("toAssureDto")
@Mapping(target = "profession", source = "csp")
AssureDto toDto(final AssureAuto entity);
```

Thanks for help

Comment: To improve the quality of your question to a point where it may receive upvotes, you should add the error message that Mapstruct generates. Just saying "not good" or "it doesn't work" will work against you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1 ([expressions](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#expressions)):

```
@Named("toAssureDto")
//assuming csp is not null, and that I want to map the value of the enum returned by .toString() that can be different from .name()
@Mapping(target = "profession", expression = "java(entity.getCsp().get().toString())")
AssureDto toDto(final AssureAuto entity);
```

Solution 2 ([adding-custom-methods](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#adding-custom-methods)):

```
@Named("toAssureDto")
@Mapping(target = "profession", source = "csp", qualifiedByName = "mapCsp")
AssureDto toDto(final AssureAuto entity);

@Named("mapCsp") 
default String mapCsp(JsonNullable<Csp> csp){
    //add your custom mapping implementation
    //here is an example assuming csp is not null, and that I want to map the value of the enum returned by .toString() that can be different from .name()
    return csp.get().toString();
}
```

Other Documentation:

- [mapping-enum-types](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-enum-types)

Comment: I’m glad to have been helpful!